# C - Store Command Line Argument as an Array of Char

Tags: c, arrays, command-line-arguments

If I have these two command line arguments, is there a way that I can take the second command line argument which is a single word containing 26 characters, separate all the letters and put them into a new array of characters?

```
./substitution qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

I tried using this syntax but I'm not sure if it is valid?

```
char mapping[] = argv[1];
```

I thought that this statement would create a new array of characters called mapping, and assign it to a string since I'm assuming `argv[1]` is a string. Then each index would have the respective characters as per the command line argument:

```
mapping[0] = 'q'
mapping[1] = 'w'
...
```

Any tips would be appreciated! :)

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, a **string** in C is stored in an *array of char* (`argv[1]` **is** an *array of char*).

Comment: Sorry if it didn't come across clearly but from my understanding argv[1] is a string but I want to take the contents of argv[1] and put it into another array, where all the characters in the string are separated out and are the elements of the new array

Comment: `char mapping[strlen(argv[1])+1]; strcpy(mapping, argv[1]);`

Comment: @M.Ng no, you didn't really understand. As a **string** isn't a type in C, it's stored in an array of `char`. Your question therefore is pointless, just access the individual characters by index like in xing's comment.

Comment: Is it possible to have an array of char without the terminating '\0' character?

Comment: Yes, but then it is not a string.

Comment: @M.Ng the `'\0'` terminates a string. Without it, the content of the array doesn't qualify as a **string**, but of course you can do that.

Comment: @M.Ng Yes, but printing it with printf("%s") would be UB

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ah I see, sorry I'm new to programming and C so perhaps didn't grasp the concepts properly.

Comment: I have to agree with Felix, strings in C are already arrays.  There is no special magic required.  You could simply write this:

strcpy(mapping,argv[1]);

to get the exact same result.\]

Comment: @FelixPalmen-- strings are of course (null-terminated) character arrays, but `argv[1]` is not an array, but a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: @DavidBowling of course, this just doesn't change anything about how it's used ;) (well, except if you wanted to apply `sizeof`...)

Comment: @DavidBowling looking at the (wrong) answer here, it's a potentially dangerous simplification I have to admit...

Comment: Finally got my program working the way I wanted it to and also understand things a little better, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

you cant assign value to an array like that. but instead you can use pointers.
argv is an array of pointers to null terminated strings. which means they has the character '\0' with ASCII value of zero at the end.

```
char *mapping = argv[1];
```

now `mapping` points to the first argument.
and if you need a copy of the first arg you should allocate enough memory for the string with `malloc`(`stdlib.h`) function and then copy it to that block of memory with `strcpy`(`string.h`).

```
char *mapping = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1); //strlen returns the size of the string not including the null character at the end.
strcpy(mapping,argv[1]);
...
free(mapping);//then you will have to free the allocated space when you are done with it.
```

now `mapping` is copy of `argv[1]` and modifying it wont affect `argc[1]`.

Comment: Better. As an aside, note that the Standard does not require character encoding to be ASCII, and there are examples of alternate encodings in use (e.g., [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)). [There are minimal restrictions on the character encoding](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1), though, and one of them is that `\0` shall be represented by a byte with all bits set to 0.